# Dockerfile WORKDIR persists in the image as well

Tags: docker

I was taking an online tutorial in order to learn about dockerfiles. There was a quiz question:

> The Dockerfile WORKDIR command changes directories:
>
> 1. only for the rest of the Dockerfile
> 2. as well as in the finished image.

My selection (wrong) was: "1. only in the rest of the Dockerfile".

Could someone correct me by giving an example where the second (correct) answer could be of benefit?

[WORKDIR in the docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#/workdir)

Comment: The quiz answer is consistent with the documentation chapter which you referenced. Does this question really need this whole story? You are asking only for the use case scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of times where you need to execute code from a specific directory, it could be that the application you are running manipulates files in the current directory, could be that the application expects config in the current directory, it could just be that the application is located in the current directory. `WORKDIR` allows the image creator to set this up so that people running the container do not need to worry about it.

For example; one use case I have had before is creating a docker container with an application that manipulates files in the current directory. Without setting `WORKDIR` you would have to bind the volume to a location and then run `cd /location` for every command:

```
docker -v $PWD:/location someimage "cd /location; somecommand"
```

By setting `WORKDIR` to `/location` you can drop the `cd`:

```
docker -v $PWD:/location someimage somecommand
```

Which is a lot more convenient.